# How to implement drag and drop between 3 Components (1 Parent and 2 Children Compoents)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I do implement a drag and drop feature with angular drag and drop.

but how to implement it between 3 components.

I created a parent component just like this:

```js
<div class="zone-vehicle-overview">
      <app-vehicle-overview [vehicleOverviewData]="vehicleOverviewData" [allDropLists]="allDropLists"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"></app-vehicle-overview>
    </div>
    <div class="zone-company-overview">
      <app-company-overview [companyOverviewData]="companyOverviewData" [allDropLists]="allDropLists"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"></app-company-overview>
    </div>
```

this component has 2 children component

vehicle overview component:

```js
<div cdkDropList id="vehicleOverview" [cdkDropListData]="vehicleOverviewData" class="vehicle-overview"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="allDropLists" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div cdkDrag>
    <div *ngFor="let item of vehicleOverviewData">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and its ts file is:

```js
export class VehicleOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() vehicleOverviewData;
  @Input() allDropLists;
  @Input() cdkDropListDropped;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

}
```

and the other child component is just same like this component.

now I want to drag and drop a list from one child componet to the other one.

but it does not work...

any idears?

Best regards,

Leo

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?